# How to write the WCF Service program which connect to database and get the data in json format

Tags: json, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I m new to Web search. I dont know how to write the program in web service please help me out 
in program i want to connect the web service to database then from there i am getting the data in json format

in client side i m using jquery mobile framework,jquery Ajax

suppose in database

id   title

1    asd

2    asw

Comment: You need to copy and paste the exact title in Google and you will get a lot much tutorials :)

Comment: See Naveed's answer if you want to do it with WCF.
If you want something which suits your "webservice-need" better/easier, you should take a look at ASP.NET Web API

Comment: Let me understand... on your server you are using WCF and exposing an endpoint which should 1)query some local DB (SQL Server?), and 2)return the response as JSON. Is that correct?

Comment: Great, then I hope my answer helps you. In the meantime, would you clean up your question so that it's easier for others to understand? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which I have copied from some of my code.

**WCF Interface definition**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IGraphDataProvider
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "devices")]
    List<string> get_devices();
}
```

**WCF Implementation**

```
public class GraphDataProvider : IGraphDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @brief Return a (possibly empty) list of devices listed in the configuration DB
     * */
    public List<string> get_devices()
    {
        // If you want to modify your headers...
        // WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";

        // Now just return a list of strings, WCF will convert to JSON
        return getDevices();
    }
}
```

That takes care of the JSON response. In case you don't know how to read your SQL DB, there are a couple ways.

1. You could use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It's easy and convenient, once you have it set up your code will look like:

   ```
   public static List<string> getDevices()
   {
       var db_context= new CfgEntities();
       var devices = from row in db_context.Devices
                     where !row.Device.StartsWith("#")
                     select row.Device.Trim();
       return devices.Distinct().ToList();
   }
   ```
2. Use the [SQL Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Microsoft. Your code will look like this:

   ```
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   // ...

   public static List<string> getDevices()
   {
       var sql_connection_ = new SqlConnection();
       sql_connection_.ConnectionString = string.Format("Server=localhost; database={0}; Trusted_Connection=SSPI", dbName);
       try
       {
           sql_connection_.Open();
       }
       // catch exceptions etc. If Open() worked then you have a connection. 

       string queryString = "SELECT [Device] from [Config].[dbo].[Devices]";
       // Now I'm just copying shamelessly from MSDN...
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, sql_connection_);
       SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       List<string> return_list = new List<string>();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
           return_list.Add((string)reader[0]);
       }

       return return_list;
   }
   ```

Comment: in web.config i have to change anything

Comment: You will if you use the Entity Framework (although the EF wizard inserts the required entry for you). I never look at my Web.config - I leave it as WCF creates it.